# setting a background to a view using relative layout programmatically xamarin forms

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mobile, layout, xamarin.forms

I have this code:

```
produtos_rl_acompanhamentos.Children.Add(grid_acompanhamentos,
    Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) =>
    {
        return (parent.Width / 2) - (grid_acompanhamentos.Width / 2);
    }),
    Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) =>
    {
        return (parent.Height / 2) - (grid_acompanhamentos.Height / 2);
    })
);

produtos_rl_acompanhamentos.Children.Add(prod_acomp_img, Constraint.RelativeToView(grid_acompanhamentos, (parent, sibling) => {
    return sibling.X;
}), Constraint.RelativeToView(grid_acompanhamentos, (parent, sibling) => {
    return sibling.Y;
}), Constraint.RelativeToView(grid_acompanhamentos, (parent, sibling) => {
    return sibling.Width;
}), Constraint.RelativeToView(grid_acompanhamentos, (parent, sibling) => {
    return sibling.Height;
}));
```

`grid_acompanhamentos` is created first, but I need it still over the `prod_acomp_img`, because the `prod_acomp_img` is the background of it. But if I add `prod_acomp_img` first, before of `prod_acomp_img`, the code doesn't recognize the `grid_acompanhamentos` to do it, the view that my image is relative to.
How can I solve that?

Can I change the children order after they were created?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution:

```
                relativeLayout.RaiseChild(view);
```